# Spring, Hibernate and multiple schemas in one codebase

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model

What is the accepted practice to use multiple database 'models' in a Spring / Hibernate combo ?

Would appreciate some help on an issue that has me scratching my head, as I am no expert in Spring/Hibernate !

We are developing a web project that up until now has been built to the specification of its first customer. All the database tables are mapped to POJOs and we use Hibernate Annotations. Very simply, the project is a CRUD application that allows end users to update database information via a front end.

We now need to support a new customer, but this customer has a slightly different specification; we will have changes to a number of tables' columns and datatypes.

We don't want to combine into one table, as this bloats up the database with lots of NULL columns (there will be 10+ unique columns per customer in some table).

The front end we can handle easily enough, as we just convert to and from JSON and the front end has been implemented per-customer from the ground up. But the backend is a bit more complicated.

We have tried a prototype where we override two tables at runtime; we converted two corresponding model classes to interfaces and implemented a concrete class per customer, loaded via the Spring configuration, e.g for a "products" table, we tried:

```
package com.mycompany.generic.model;
public interface Product
```

and then

```
package com.mycompany.customera.model;
@Table(name="products")
public class CustomerAProduct implements Properties {
  String colour;
  int weight;
}
```

or

```
package com.mycompany.customerb.model;
@Table(name="products")
public class CustomerBProduct implements Properties {
  String colour;
  int volume;
  Double price;
}
```

..where Spring loads, as a runtime option, *com.mycompany.customera* or *customerb* depending on configuration, along with any customer-specific validations/service classes to act on the new POJO's. You see that the underlying columns can be different.

However, I am hesitate to pitch into implementing this, because..

- Almost every model class will need converting and implementing per-customer, not just the ones that are different. This is because we have many joins (OneToMany etc) within the model classes, Hibernate does not let you join to an interface (eg [HHH-4338](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4338))
- some sort of util/factory is required to generate new instances of classes, as where we used to do *new Properties* we do not know whether to use *new CustomerAProperties()* or *new CustomerBProperties()* (for the same reason, we cannot use TargetEntity to solve the above problem, because this requires a .class file which cannot be set in the code)

These seem pretty major downsides so I am trying to research a better way to do it. We can build per-customer, via Maven, but then I am not sure how to implement this in a way that isn't going to break Eclipse while we develop locally..

Or, is there some other method that I am not aware of ?

thanks in advance for any suggestions or pointers on what to research etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Or, is there some other method that I am not aware of ?

Any reason you cannot switch from annotation based mapping to xml mapping?

Each customer gets a set of XML mapping files.  Now you only need to subclass when the model truly differs between customers.